# I'm not French and I can't drive. Can I learn how to drive in France?

Tags: france, driving-license

I was born in Brazil, and recently moved to France, where I will live for about two and a half years. Due to time issues, I wasn't able to go to a driving school in Brazil and obtain my driving license before coming to France.

I was wondering if I can do the lessons and test and obtain a French driving license. Currently I don't have any European passport, but I am a *jus sanguinis* italian citizen, so I could obtain my european passport in the course of these two and half years, if that is necessary (I don't believe it is, just saying for general information, you never know).

I searched a lot on the internet about this subject but all the sites I found were directed to people with an American driving license that want to drive in France. I don't have any driving license. Can I learn how to drive in France?

Comment: According to https://www.internations.org/go/moving-to-france/country-facts/the-nuts-and-bolts-of-getting-a-french-driving-license the easiest way is to enrol with a driving school, then take the written and practical tests. The school will help you complete the necessary registration formalities.

Comment: In all countries where I know it, any _resident_ can learn driving, take the required tests, and get a driving license.

Comment: To follow up to @gnasher729's comment: in general, countries are much happier if you get a licence from them, rather than having to recognize someone else's (they trust their own licence).  I cannot image you would have any difficulty; you may have more difficulty when getting your French licence recognized in Brazil.

Comment: As an example, a German living in the U.K. can get a British license without problems, but cannot get a German license or even extend an expiring German license.

Comment: @gnasher729, that's a EU thing, you must renew your license in your member state of residence

Comment: When you google in France, you should switch to France sites  but don't know why ... so I google for you https://fossbytes.com/google-search-change-country/

Comment: Internationaly driver's licences are **residence** based. When you return to Brazil with a French licence, convert it to a Brazilian one. Proof of driving experience (insurance) while in France is **very** helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In France you have 2 exams to achieve in order to get a driving license:

1st: The theorical exam usually called Code / Code de la route, it is a multiple choice questionnary, you can train it either in a driving school where there is training session or online. It's easier with driving school as they manage your registration for the official exam session but also more expensive.

Once you get it you can move to the practice.

2nd: Once you have finished the theorical part you can start the practice, usually you'll go to a driving school (you will likely go on with the one where you trained the theorical part). You'll have a first hour of driving where they evaluate your level and estimate how many hours of practice you need (usually 20 hours minimum, between 20 and 30 unless you are slow at learning). Each hour is billed, the average cost is between 30€ and 40€ per hour.
Once you think you are ready you can see with your driving school to get a appointment for the official test.
You'll have to drive with an official examinator for about 30 minutes, he / she will ask you theorical questions, tell you the way you have to follow, ask you to park in different ways etc.
A few days later you'll know if you got your license or not. If you did not you can try again at the next possible appointment.

Good luck !

Edit: I paid about 1000-1200€ for the whole process which is the average cost if you are an average learner and pass the 2 tests in one time.